# Segmentation fault Php5 and ODBC

Tags: php, ms-access, ubuntu, odbc

I have an application developed in laravel with MySql database and Ubuntu 14.04. However I need to read and do some selects of a microsoft access file (.mdb). I am using the ODBC MDB driver (libmdbodbc) to do this job but when i need to do inner join of some tables or when i have a lot of information in a table, the system gives me this error "segmentation fault"
Did i install the ODBC MDB driver wrongly?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Based on my own experience I suspect that you haven't done anything wrong, it's just that ODBC support for Access databases on Ubuntu is simply broken. I have tried on several occasions to do what you describe and I've never been able to resolve the "segmentation fault" problem.

Comment: @Gord Thompson how did you resolve this problem?